# Познание исскуство кибербезопасности

Tags: безопасность

Я бы хотел начать изучать сферу кибербезопасности. Люди, которые знают, посоветуйте, с чего стоит начать

Comment: Геймдев и глубочайшую архитектуру процессора уже выучил?

Comment: Архитектуру выучил, геймдев - на стадии изучения ЯП, хочу что-то, что бы отдохнуть от геймдева

Comment: Для начала нужно начать не с айти, а с юридических вопросов: чтобы знать, какие сроки и за что положены.

Comment: Проще всего поступить в университет на специальность "кибербезопасность".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу посоветовать несколько странное решение. Начни практиковаться во взломах. Чем больше взломов ты совершил - тем больше ты узнал лазеек. Узнал лазейку - пробуй ее закрыть. 
Протестируй собственную Wi-Fi сеть на уязвимость)

Самое первое мучение - установи Линукс. Arch/Kali
И начинай проникновения, стараясь с каждым разом после успешного взлома сделать так, чтобы в дальнейшем тебе было сложнее взломать. В идеале - невозможно

Для начала - хватит с головой увлечься и обучиться азам

Comment: Кажется, при таком подходе, потолок настанет совсем скоро. На взломе собственного `Wi-Fi`, скорее всего, всё и закончится. Для этого даже отдельный термин есть — `Script kiddie`. IMHO, за любыми осмысленными взломами должна быть твёрдая мат. часть, которая есть только у специалистов в конкретной области.